# Grid lines not showing up

Tags: javascript, d3.js

i am learning d3 and doing some practice.

I want to build something like this

[image]

and my code is this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  /* set the CSS */

  .blue {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  .green {
    fill: greenyellow;
  }

  .yellow {
    fill: yellow;
  }

  .red {
    fill: red;
  }

  .violet {
    fill: violet;
  }
  .seperatorLine {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>
<body>
  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var color = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "violet", "blue"];

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // append a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // get the data
    d3.csv(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pravinpoudel/file-host/main/neuroticism.csv"
    ).then(function (data) {
      // format the data
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.sales = +d.value;
      });

      // Scale the range of the data in the domains
      x.domain(
        data.map(function (d) {
          return d.factor;
        })
      );
      y.domain([0, 20]);

      // append the rectangles for the bar chart
      svg
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function (d, i) {
          return color[i];
        })
        .attr("x", function (d) {
          return x(d.factor);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function (d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function (d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });

      svg
        .append("line")
        .data(data)
        .attr("class", "seperatorLine")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", function (d, i) {
          return i * (height / 20) + 1;
        })
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", function (d, i) {
          return i * (height / 20) + 5;
        });

      // add the x Axis
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // add the y Axis
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

i am not able to add those line in each axis and label in between the bar !!

can anyone please help me !!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `append` and `data` like you did. You need to use `selection.data` followed by `enter`, just like you did for the rectangles:

```
svg.selectAll(null)
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    //etc...
```

Here's your code with that change:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
  /* set the CSS */
  
  .blue {
    fill: steelblue;
  }
  
  .green {
    fill: greenyellow;
  }
  
  .yellow {
    fill: yellow;
  }
  
  .red {
    fill: red;
  }
  
  .violet {
    fill: violet;
  }
  
  .seperatorLine {
    fill: red;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <!-- load the d3.js library -->
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {
        top: 20,
        right: 20,
        bottom: 30,
        left: 40
      },
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var color = ["blue", "green", "yellow", "red", "violet", "blue"];

    // set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleBand().range([0, width]).padding(0.1);
    var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

    // append the svg object to the body of the page
    // append a 'group' element to 'svg'
    // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
    var svg = d3
      .select("body")
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // get the data
    d3.csv(
      "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pravinpoudel/file-host/main/neuroticism.csv"
    ).then(function(data) {
      // format the data
      data.forEach(function(d) {
        d.sales = +d.value;
      });

      // Scale the range of the data in the domains
      x.domain(
        data.map(function(d) {
          return d.factor;
        })
      );
      y.domain([0, 20]);

      // append the rectangles for the bar chart
      svg
        .selectAll(".bar")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")
        .attr("class", function(d, i) {
          return color[i];
        })
        .attr("x", function(d) {
          return x(d.factor);
        })
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", function(d) {
          return y(d.value);
        })
        .attr("height", function(d) {
          return height - y(d.value);
        });

      svg.selectAll(null)
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("line")
        .attr("class", "seperatorLine")
        .attr("x1", 0)
        .attr("y1", function(d, i) {
          return i * (height / 20) + 1;
        })
        .attr("x2", width)
        .attr("y2", function(d, i) {
          return i * (height / 20) + 5;
        })
        .style("stroke", "#ccc");

      // add the x Axis
      svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

      // add the y Axis
      svg.append("g").call(d3.axisLeft(y));
    });
  </script>
</body>
```

Three observations:

1. Your y positions seem to be incorrect;
2. If you want the lines behind the rectangles, append them first.
3. By far the easiest way to do what you want is simply using `tickSizeInner` in your axis generator.

Comment: thank you i didn't know about ticksizeinner which seems to be a nice option but still i am not able to figure out how to put value in between the bar !! i know that i have to retrive that value from the data but i dont know how to put it on center

Comment: That seems to be a separate issue.